# jQuery FormBuilder - Disable Attribute on Default Field

Tags: javascript, jquery, formbuilder

I'm using the following jQuery Formbuilder (http://formbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/formBuilder/options/typeUserDisabledAttrs/)

Docs indicate you can disable a field attribute as follows:

```
var options = {
   typeUserDisabledAttrs: {
      'text': [
         'name',
         'description',
    ]
  }
};
$(container).formBuilder(options);
```

However the above would apply to all text controls.

Is there anyway to disable attributes on default fields - These fields appear on all forms and person configuring the form should not be allowed to remove the fields nor change some attributes such as the name etc.

```
var options = {
         defaultFields: [
            {
                "type": "text",
                "required": true,
                "label": "Subject",
                "className": "form-control",
                "name": "Subject",
                "subtype": "text",
                "disabledFieldButtons": ['remove']
             }],
         disabledActionButtons: ['clear']
 };
 $(container).formBuilder(options);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've figured out a soultion by doing the following:

```
 typeUserEvents: {
                text: {
                    onadd: function (fld) {
                        var $nameField = $('.fld-name', fld);

                        if ($nameField.val() == "Subject")
                            $nameField.prop('disabled', true);

                    }
                }
            }
```